# How to bind Dictionary object to checkedlistbox using WPF

Tags: wpf, checkedlistbox

> I have a generic dictionary collection Dictionary. I need to bind the displaymember path key to the content of the checkbox and checkbox Ischecked property to the value member of the Dictionary

```
 private Dictionary<string, bool> _columnHeaderList;
    public Dictionary<string, bool> ColumnHeaderList
    {
        get { return _columnHeaderList; }
        set { _columnHeaderList = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ColumnHeaderList"); }
    }

    private Dictionary<string, bool> GetColumnList()
    {
        Dictionary<string, bool> dictColumns = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
        Array columns = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ColumnHeaders));
        int arrayIndex=0;
        for(int i=0;i<columns.Length;i++)
        {
            dictColumns.Add(columns.GetValue(arrayIndex).ToString(), true);
        }
        return dictColumns;

    }
```

> My XAML looks like

```
 <ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="200" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding ColumnHeaderList}"
             VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding key}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value}"></CheckBox>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>               
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>           
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Can you please add the code that's needed to make it compile? (RaisePropertyChanged and ColumnHeaders)?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use OneWay binding if you bind to Dictionary because the KeyValuePair has read-only properties.

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding Key, Mode=OneWay}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}" Width="100" /></CheckBox>
```

make sure you have set the DataContext. Note this will not update the dictionary values when the user presses on the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Since Value property is readonly and OneWay binding will not allow you track the changes if user checks or unchecks the checkboxes. It is recommended to bind them with an array new class ListItem:

```
class ListItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}

private ListItem[] GetColumnList()
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(ColumnHeaders))
               .Select(h => new ListItem{ Text = h.ToString(),IsChecked = true})
               .ToArray();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah its possible and it should work too, although you need to bind with Value with Binding Mode as `OneWay` since the dictionary value can't be set since its readOnly. If you wish to change the value you can hook the `Command(if following MVVVM)` or can handle in code behind on `Checked event`.

Also Binding for `Key` is not correct, replace your `key`with `Key`. Your final xaml should be like this -

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="200" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding ColumnHeaderList}"
             VerticalAlignment="Top">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <CheckBox Content="{Binding Key}"
                     IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>               
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>           
</ListBox>
```

Note i have changed the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` with `DataTemplate` since i could not see any hierarchy in the template.